# Redshift or ANY SQL: Update a table with with similar rows whose times are within 30 seconds

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've got this table:

```
prod | customer |   city  | num  |       time         | isextra
-----+----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------
 1   | Jim      |  Venice |  5   |2015-08-27 1:10:00  | 0
 1   | Jim      |  Venice |  5   |2015-08-27 1:10:15  | 0
 1   | Jim      |  Venice |  5   |2015-08-27 1:10:28  | 0
 4   | Jane     |  Vienna |  8   |2018-06-04 2:20:43  | 0
 4   | Jane     |  Vienna |  8   |2018-06-04 2:20:43  | 0
 4   | Jane     |  Vienna |  8   |2018-06-04 2:20:49  | 0
 4   | Jane     |  Vienna |  8   |2018-06-04 2:30:55  | 0
 7   | Jack     | Vilnius |  4   |2015-09-15 2:20:55  | 0
 7   | Jake     |   Vigo  |  9   |2018-01-01 10:20:05 | 0
 7   | Jake     |   Vigo  |  2   |2018-01-01 10:20:25 | 0
```

Now take all rows that are similar by prod, customer,  city, num then any row whose time is within 30 seconds of the first in the group, its 'isextra' field is UPDATED to 1, and have this be the result:

```
prod | customer |   city  | num  |       time         | isextra
-----+----------+---------+------+--------------------+-------
 1   | Jim      |  Venice |  5   |2015-08-27 1:10:00  | 0
 1   | Jim      |  Venice |  5   |2015-08-27 1:10:15  | 1
 1   | Jim      |  Venice |  5   |2015-08-27 1:10:28  | 1
 4   | Jane     |  Vienna |  8   |2018-06-04 2:20:43  | 0
 4   | Jane     |  Vienna |  8   |2018-06-04 2:20:43  | 1
 4   | Jane     |  Vienna |  8   |2018-06-04 2:20:49  | 1
 4   | Jane     |  Vienna |  8   |2018-06-04 2:30:55  | 0
 7   | Jack     | Vilnius |  4   |2015-09-15 2:20:55  | 0
 7   | Jake     |   Vigo  |  9   |2018-01-01 10:20:05 | 0
 7   | Jake     |   Vigo  |  2   |2018-01-01 10:20:25 | 0
```

Here's the table and data:

```
create table mytable (prod int, customer varchar, city varchar, num int, time timestamp, isextra smallint);


insert into mytable values (1, 'Jim', 'Venice', 5, '2015-08-27 1:10:00',  0);
insert into mytable values (1, 'Jim', 'Venice',  5, '2015-08-27 1:10:15',  0);
insert into mytable values (1, 'Jim', 'Venice',  5, '2015-08-27 1:10:28',  0);
insert into mytable values (4, 'Jane',  'Vienna',   8,   '2018-06-04 2:20:43',   0);
insert into mytable values (4, 'Jane',  'Vienna',   8,   '2018-06-04 2:20:43',   0);
insert into mytable values (4, 'Jane',  'Vienna',   8,   '2018-06-04 2:20:49',   0);
insert into mytable values (4, 'Jane',  'Vienna',   8,   '2018-06-04 2:30:55',   0);
insert into mytable values (7, 'Jack', 'Vilnius',   4,   '2015-09-15 2:20:55',   0);
insert into mytable values (7, 'Jake',   'Vigo',    9,   '2018-01-01 10:20:05',  0);
insert into mytable values (7, 'Jake',   'Vigo',    2,   '2018-01-01 10:20:25',  0);
```

All I have is this so far:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET isextra = 1
FROM ( 
  select *, 
  row_number() over (partition by prod, customer, city, num order by time asc)
    as t from mytable
) AS sequence
```

Stuck here...

Any ideas appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this flies in PostgreSQL 8.0 (redshift), but it's worth a try:

```
update mytable a
  set isextra = 1 
  from (
    select prod, customer, city, num, min(time) as mintime
      from mytable 
      group by prod, customer, city, num
  ) b
  where a.prod = b.prod
    and a.customer = b.customer
    and a.city = b.city
    and a.num = b.num
    and a.time <= b.mintime + interval '30 seconds'
    and a.time <> b.mintime;
```

Result:

```
prod  customer  city     num  time                   isextra
----  --------  ----     ---  ---------------------  -------
1     Jim       Venice   5    2015-08-27 01:10:00.0  0
1     Jim       Venice   5    2015-08-27 01:10:15.0  1
1     Jim       Venice   5    2015-08-27 01:10:28.0  1
4     Jane      Vienna   8    2018-06-04 02:20:43.0  0
4     Jane      Vienna   8    2018-06-04 02:20:43.0  0
4     Jane      Vienna   8    2018-06-04 02:20:49.0  1
4     Jane      Vienna   8    2018-06-04 02:30:55.0  0
7     Jack      Vilnius  4    2015-09-15 02:20:55.0  0
7     Jake      Vigo     2    2018-01-01 10:20:25.0  0
7     Jake      Vigo     9    2018-01-01 10:20:05.0  0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not quite there, it sets all isextra to 1 except for one row.

Comment: I think I got it this time. Please review.

Comment: Yes, that's it!! Thank you very much!

Comment: @HuFlungPu . . . How does this get the right answer with the duplicate rows?

Comment: I don't think it does. Actually, I don't know if that's actually possible, since there's no way of differentiate them.

Comment: FYI postgres 8 <> redshift. Redshift has many things that are not in PG 8

Answer (score 1):

I would write a `select` using window functions as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when time > min_time and
                  time < dateadd(minute, 30, min_time)
             then 1 else 0 
        end) as is_extra
from (select t.*,
             min(time) over (partition by prod, customer, city, num) as min_time
      from t
     ) t;
```

The only issue are the duplicate times at the same row.  We could fix that as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when time > min_time and time < dateadd(minute, 30, min_time) and seqnum <> 0
             then 1 else 0 
        end) as is_extra
from (select t.*,
             min(time) over (partition by prod, customer, city, num) as min_time,
             row_number() over (partition by prod, customer, city, num order by time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Unfortunately, turning this into an `update` is really tricky because of the exact duplicate rows in your example.

If you have a unique id on each row, then you can turn this into an `update`:

```
update t
    set t.is_extra = tt.new_is_extra
    from (select t.*,
                 (case when time > min_time and time < dateadd(minute, 30, min_time) and seqnum <> 0
             then 1 else 0 
                  end) as new_is_extra
          from (select t.*,
                       min(time) over (partition by prod, customer, city, num) as min_time,
                       row_number() over (partition by prod, customer, city, num order by time) as seqnum
                from t
                ) t
         ) tt
     where t.id = tt.id
```

Comment: Thanks, except I need it to Update.

Comment: @HuFlungPu . . . You have exact duplicate rows, which makes that pretty hard to do.

Comment: yeah I did that on purpose to try and weed those out if they happen.

Comment: You're better to start a transaction, create a temp table, hold the results, delete the records that match and insert new records.